How to set cookie on localhost on developing environment currently?
I'm on a session authentication work with nextjs and express. I installed express-session and finished a session login function, tried on postman and it works fine.
But when I call the login request through my nextjs webapp, the session id can't set to the cookie.
I read some article saids that I need to set "secure" as true when I set "sameSite" as none.
The problem is I dont' have any certificate for my development, so are there any solution to do the session login purpose without certificate on my development?
My express api domain is: http://localhost:3000
My webapp domain is: http://localhost:3001
My current cors settings:
origin: true,
methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
preflightContinue: false,
optionsSuccessStatus: 204,
credentials: true,

My current cookie settings:
  path: "/",
  maxAge: 180000,
  secure: false,
  httpOnly: false,
  sameSite: "none",

